# Converting Electron app to UWP app

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, uwp, electron

I need some tips on how to convert a Electron app to Universal Windows Platform. I have imported all the JavaScript files into Visual studio 2017 and chosen Universal Windows Platform platform. My main problem is that I have renderers (renderer.js) which does not want to run when I compile the solution in Visual studio. I can build the solution, but when I run it I only get a white window. Any tips on how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So i have found a solution for my problem.

I found that in the JS(UWP) applications manifest it was starting some main.js file. I changed this file to start the wanted index.html file and it resolved my problems. Sorry for having so little information to go on. Also enabling the KIOSK mode was really simple so everything is working out as wanted.

Comment: can you go a little into detail how you did this? Would be great to have this info (I'm facing the same problem)

Comment: so.. how did you enable the kiosk mode..? I am currently searching for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Are you just wanting to submit on the store or want a *proper* universal app? If it's just the former, take a look at https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-store

Comment: I need to app to be in UWP. So using a tool like you suggested is not an option. I am thinking it might be possible to call all the render functions manually from the index.html file?

Comment: Electron is designed for 'Desktop' app, not for UWP app.

Comment: But what does that mean exactly? If i phase some of the HTML code that is within the app, into the index.html file that the UWP loads, it shows the content. So why can i not use the existing renders to display the content into the window that UWP creates, instead of using electron to display the content.